# Formatting \addchap

Tags: formatting, koma-script

My apologies in advance for such a banal question. I am using \addchap in a document and, would like to centre the chapter heading it creates. Could someone help me out with this please?

A MWE:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Gill Sans}
  \usepackage{lettrine}
  \usepackage[automark,headsepline=.25pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{ {../img/} }
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage[british]{babel}
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}%changed to small caps in headers
  %\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalsize}
  \addtokomafont{pagehead}{\small}
  %\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalsize}
  \addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\small}
  \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} %for headings
  %\addtokomafont{disposition}
  \chead{Ben Francis}
  \ofoot{} %Author Name
  \ifoot{} % Chapter Number
  \lehead{\pagemark}
  \rohead{\pagemark}
  \cohead{\mytitle}
  \renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
  \linespread{1.05}
  \usepackage{hyphenat}
  \tolerance=1000
  \hyphenpenalty=1000
  \renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in,
%   verbose,
%   tmargin=0.75in,
%   bmargin=0.75in,
%   inner=0.75in,
%   outer=0.5in,
%   headheight=0.1in,
%   headsep=0.15in,
%   footskip=0.45in,
    twoside}
  \newcommand{\mytitle}{Tears in the Rain} 
  \newcommand{\emptx}[1]{\textit{#1}}

%\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%indent=.25in,
%font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
%font=\fontsize{15}{10}
%]{section}

%\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\fontspec{Gill Sans}}
%\setkomafont{subsection}{\small}
%\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\small}
%\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize}
%\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize}

\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

 \setlength\parindent{8pt}

\begin{document}
    \title{\mytitle}
    \author{}
    \date{}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{flushright}
        {\huge \mytitle}
        \par\end{flushright}{\huge \par}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=4in,height=1.5in]{./titrbensig}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{flushright}
        \Huge{Tears in the Rain}
        \par\end{flushright}{\Huge \par}

    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{center}
        \emph{Copyright}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \textcopyright{ 2014 Ben Francis All rights reserved.}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\paperwidth}
            No part of this publication may be reproduced, stored in a retrieval system, or transmitted in any form, or by any means;
            mechanical, electrical, photocopying, scanning, recording or
            otherwise, without prior written consent from the publishers. Every
            effort has been made to contact all copyright holders. The author and
            publisher will gladly rectify any omissions.
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{center}
        ISBN:
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.2in}
    \begin{center}
        A CIP Record for this book is available from the British
        Library.
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{center}
        Typeset in \LaTeXe
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\tableofcontents

\addchap{PREFACE}
\input{./titr_pref.tex}     
\mainmatter
\addchap{ONE}
\input{./titr01.tex}
\end document
```

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Can you give a MWE?

Comment: Do you only want the chapter headings centered you added with `\addchap`? Or all the chapter headings?

Comment: Benjamin- Each chapter heading added by an instance of \addchap (I am using only \addchap).

Comment: Apologies - I have no idea how to add a MWE via an edit so, made a bit of a mess of this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All chapters centred**

If all chapters should be centered use

```
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\blindtext
\chapter{Numbered chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

**Only unnumbered chapters centered**

If only unnumbered chapters should be centered and there is no `chapterprefix` you can redefine `\chapterlinesformat`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\centering}{}%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
```

But with option `chapterprefix` command  `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` must be redefined.

```
\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\centering}{}%
  #2#3%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass
  %[chapterprefix]
  {scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\centering}{}%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\centering}{}%
  #2#3%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\blindtext
\chapter{Numbered chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: esdd: Thank you it works just great! I am an author new to Latex - so still learning and climbing the hill....Cheers